# Binding and writing values back to parent scope without using isolated scope in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

What is the preferred way of passing data back to parent scope in Angular, without isolated scopes?

Given I have a directive `x`, and want to know it's value `a`, I want to do something like:

```
<x a="some.obj.myA"></x>
current a: {{some.obj.myA}}
```

I would define the `x` directive like so:

```
app.directive('x', function() {
    var a = {};
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            var parentExpression = $attrs.a;

            // ???
        },
        replace: true,
        template: ...
    };
});
```

Now, I always want to keep "`$scope.$parent[parentExpression]`" (pseudocode) equal to the value of the local `a`. However, this should even work, if `parentExpression` refers to a nested object, array or any other sort of assignable expression.

How could I go about doing that?

Comment: You dont seem to create a child scope either, so it is _the_ parent scope you are referring to, you could just do `var parentExpressionValue = $scope.$eval($attrs.a)`

Comment: Directives, by default, share a scope with their parent. So without a `scope` attribute in your directive config then `$scope.myObj` in the directive is the same as `$scope.myObj` in the parent

Comment: @NicholasThomson Yes, but it is copy-on-write. Besides, what if I don't want to write `myObj` but `myObj.x.y.z` (based on a string, passed in as argument, similar to how `ng-model` works)?

Comment: @Domi that is where you can use $scope.$eval(expression) as i mentioned in my prev comment. It will get you the value..

Comment: @PSL Yes, it *gets* the value, but does not write it to the parent scope.

Comment: @Domi it is not parent. It is the same scope. You mean modify it and write it back? use `<x ng-model="some.obj.myA"></x>` and use 4th argument of link function (say ctrl) which will be the ng-model and set require `ng-model` in directive settings. Then use `ctrl.$setViewValue(newValue); ctrl.$render();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple options:

**Using `ng-model`**

Example:

```
app.directive('x', function() {
  var a = {};
  return {
    require:'ngModel', //require it, you can make it options as well with ?
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl) {
       var currentValue = ctrl.$viewValue;
       //... do something with the value and then set it back
       ctrl.$setViewValue(newValue);
       ctrl.$render();
    },
    replace: true,
    template: ...
  };
});

<x ng-model="some.obj.myA"></x>
```

If your directive is intended to change the value of the modal probably you are looking at [$formatters/$parsers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers) as well. Also take a look at [`$viewChangeListeners`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$viewChangeListeners) if you plan to watch for view value change.

```js
 angular.module('app', []).directive('x', function() {
   var a = {};
   return {
     require: 'ngModel', //require it, you can make it options as well with ?
     restrict: 'E',
     link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, ctrl) {
       //override render function
       ctrl.$render = function() {
         var currentValue = ctrl.$viewValue;
         console.log(currentValue);
         //... do something with the value and then set it back
         ctrl.$setViewValue(currentValue + "Updated");
       };
     },
     replace: true,

   };
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-init="some={obj:{myA:'hey'}}">
  {{some.obj.myA}}
  <x ng-model="some.obj.myA"></x>
</div>
```

---

**Using [`$parse`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse)**

Use $parse service and create `getter` and `setter` from the expression and update it back. Here you can use multiple attribute bindings.

Example:

```
   link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
       var getA = $parse($attrs.a);
       var setA = getter.assign; 
       var currentValue = getter($scope);
       //... update to new value and set it back
       setA ($scope, currentValue  + "Updated")
     },
```

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('x', ['$parse', function($parse) {
   var a = {};
   return {
     restrict: 'E',
     link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
       var getter = $parse($attrs.a);
       var setter = getter.assign;
       console.log(getter($scope),setter($scope, "Updated"));
     },
     replace: true,

   };
 }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-init="some={obj:{myA:'hey'}}">
  {{some.obj.myA}}
  <x a="some.obj.myA"></x>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine. Thank you! Is there a way that I can name the attribute myself, not call it `ng-model`?

Comment: @Domi ng-model is the right way in your case because it gives you all the apis required to update/access/watch the bound model.

Comment: What if I want to handle two different models? Of course I can merge multiple models into a single `ng-model` but there are several scenarios where that is not a good idea.

Comment: @Domi you could otherwise use attribute inject $parse and then assign method?